# Traci4matlab: How to solve the 'Error using traci.socket'?

Tags: matlab

I am a new user of traci4matlab. After I install traci4matlab in my matlabR2019a by Add-on. I tried to run the traci_test.m. But errors occured:
Dose anyone know how to fix it? Thanks!

Error using traci.Socket/connect (line 25)
Java exception occurred: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

```
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)

at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)

at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)

at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)

at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)

at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)

at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)

at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)

at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
```

Error in matlab.internal.lang.fwdSubsref (line 6)
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = subsref(A,s);

Error in traci.init (line 65)
        connections(label).connect(host, port);

Error in traci_test (line 24)
[traciVersion,sumoVersion] = traci.init();

Comment: You should ask the creator directly on the file exchange submission page.